# Hi, I want to convert the comma separated nvarchar to int list in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I want to convert the comma separated nvarchar to int list in sql.How I can achieve that?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Add some sample table data and the expected result (as well formatted text.) Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Hi I have done that.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function as

```
    USE [QA]
    GO
    /****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[NvarcharToIntList]    Script Date: 5/29/2017 2:42:50 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[NvarcharToIntList] (@InStr VARCHAR(MAX))
    RETURNS @TempTab TABLE
       (id int not null)
    AS
    BEGIN
        ;-- Ensure input ends with comma
        SET @InStr = REPLACE(@InStr + ',', ',,', ',')
        DECLARE @SP INT
    DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(1000)
    WHILE PATINDEX('%,%', @INSTR ) <> 0 
    BEGIN
       SELECT  @SP = PATINDEX('%,%',@INSTR)
       SELECT  @VALUE = LEFT(@INSTR , @SP - 1)
       SELECT  @INSTR = STUFF(@INSTR, 1, @SP, '')
       INSERT INTO @TempTab(id) VALUES (@VALUE)
    END
        RETURN
    END
@users = '158,159'
```

then I am using it as `dbo.ResidentAssessment.LastUpdatedBy in(SELECT * FROM dbo.NvarcharToIntList(@users))`

Answer (score 0):

Starting from SQL 2016 there is a STRING_SPLIT function

from the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)

```
DECLARE @tags NVARCHAR(400) = 'clothing,road,,touring,bike'  

SELECT value  
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@tags, ',');
```

Comment: I was in 2005 sql

Comment: I'll add the corresponding tag to your post :)

Comment: It is done, I have answered above myself